# Can't center a div

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a problem with setting up my menu for a website. The whole website is centrated whith margin: auto. By some reason the menu does not centrate because it's a div that contain links, the buttons. Each button link has a background image. This is because the images for the buttons are 315px wide and include the overlay images. For example, when the user holds over this image the image moves 105px to the left and shows the mouseover option. (View code)

This is the .html: (don't mind the id names for the buttons, didn't feel like changing :D and yes I'm swedish)

```
    <body>
    <!--Banner-->
    <img src="/header/picture.png" />
    <img src="/header/banner.png" />

    <!--Pre-loads the images for menu-->
    <img src="/header/start.png" style="display: none;" />
    <img src="/header/bestall.png" style="display: none;" />
    <img src="/header/priser.png" style="display: none;" />
    <img src="/header/omoss.png" style="display: none;" />
    <img src="/header/support.png" style="display: none;" />
    <img src="/header/filarkiv.png" style="display: none;" />

    <!--Menu-->
    <div id="menu">
    <a href="index.php" id="startknapp"></a>
    <a href="index.php" id="priserknapp"></a>
    <a href="index.php" id="bestallknapp"></a>
    <a href="index.php" id="omossknapp"></a>
    <a href="index.php" id="supportknapp"></a>
    <a href="index.php" id="filarkivknapp"></a>
    <img src="/header/box.png" id="box" />
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    <p>Hi!</p>
    <p>This is one paragraph</p>
    <p>And this is another.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

And this is how I have set up the buttons in the css for the menu:

```
    /*Startknappen*/
    #startknapp
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        width: 105px;
        height: 35px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-image:url(start.png);
    }

    #startknapp:hover 
    {
        background-position: -105px 0; 
    }

    #startknapp:active 
    {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /*Priserknappen*/
    #priserknapp
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 105px;
        width: 105px;
        height: 35px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-image:url(priser.png);
    }

    #priserknapp:hover 
    {
        background-position: -105px 0;
    }

    #priserknapp:active 
    {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ... and so on for the other buttons...
```

Here is some of the .css:

```
    #html, body 
    {
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 800px;
        height: 800px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    #menu
    {
        height: 35px;
        width: 800px;
    }

    #content
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 800px;
        background-color: ;
    }
```

The problem now is that, as written above, the menu won't centrate. However when I do position: absolute; for #menu it does centrate. Only problem is that content then overlaps the menu, and I don't want that. I want content to start 0px after the bottom of menu. Here are some images of how it looks:

Won't centrate: 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/leftra.png

Position: Absolute:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/centerh.png

Hope someone can help me get this right. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: At a glance <div id="menu"> hasn't been close, that might be affecting it.

Comment: Can you show a working demo or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I forget the closing div and body when creating thread here. Fixed it now. Still got the same problem.

Comment: I will upload the page as a demo when I get home in a half an hour. Sorry, should have thought of that before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hasn't been closed, I don't know if you haven't closed the body tag either or just cut that off of your copy-pasting.

Also, the style for#menu should include "position: relative" if you are setting the menu items with position absolute, that way they will  be positioned relative to the menu container and not the body of the page.

Also, I'm not sure what this code will do:

```
#html, body 
    {
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 800px;
        height: 800px;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

You're trying to position it centrally with a width, but then saying that it should stretch to every corner with the portion that says "top: 0; right: 0 etc"

It would be much better to have a wrapper like such:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    All content in here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { margin: 0 auto; width: 800px; }
```

*Edit*: Also just noticed, nice to see someone else using Ubuntu ;)

*Edit2*: It would be much better if you positioned your nav items with floats instead of "position: absolute" for more information see [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/)

For more information on positioning, which you might also want, see [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/)

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't answer your question, it's difficult to try and fix it without looking at a working model sometimes.

Comment: I forget the closing div and body when creating thread here. Fixed it now. Still got the same problem.

Comment: Did you try the CSS/HTML I suggested? Did that help?

Comment: I am looking at the rest of your answer as well, just letting you know so you don't think I'm not :P

Comment: Thanks! The position: relative solved my problem. Thank you so much :)

I will take the rest of your post in consideration for future coding as well.

Answer (score 1):

As Sean Dunwoody said, you need to add position: relative to div.menu. When using position: absolute, items are positioned to the last item to be given a position property. Since you haven't positioned any of your divs other than the menu items, they're moving up through the hierarchy of divs and positioning themselves in relation to the body tag. By adding position: relative to div.menu, you tell div.menu where it needs to be (i.e, relative to everything else), and then the buttons know where they need to be (positioned absolutely in regards to their parent div, div.menu)